# How to close <a> tag right after <img>?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

This is what I'm doing:

```
%p
  %a{href:'/a'}
    %img{src:'/img'}
```

This is what it looks like in the HTML:

```
<p>
<a href="/a">
<img src="/img">
</a>
</p>
```

I need this instead:

```
<p>
<a href="/a"><img src="/img"></a>
</p>
```

What should I do to my HAML config or the `.haml` code? I'm with Sinatra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a case for the [whitespace removal feature](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#whitespace-removal--and-):

```
%p
  %a{href:'/a'}<
    %img{src:'/img'}
```

or:

```
%p
  %a{href:'/a'}
    %img{src:'/img'}>
```

both produce the same output:

```html
<p>
<a href='/a'><img src='/img'></a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest option would be probably to include in `css` something like:

```
a > img { display: inline-block }
```